# How to use bimg (Golang package for image processing) on Windows?

Tags: go

I am trying to use [bimg](https://github.com/h2non/bimg) to make some image processing in my Go application, but it requires libvips or gcc 4.6+ or clang 3.0+, which doesn't seem to work on Windows. How can I make it work (without running Docker container)?

Comment: You could try it on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Look for Ubuntu in the windows App Store, download it, and then try running the installation script in an Ubuntu terminal