# How to use bimg with clang compiler instead of gcc?

Tags: go, gcc, clang, vips

I have `clang` installed and available in PATH, but when I'm trying to build my project, I'm getting this error:

```
# github.com/h2non/bimg
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

How to make it work with clang? I've tried `gcc`, but I got another error: `sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled`

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Have you set the CC CXX environment variables? The error sounds like you only installed a 32bit gcc.

Comment: That's probably true. Are you running this on WSL? (I'm assuming this is a follow-up question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645621/how-to-use-bimg-golang-package-for-image-processing-on-windows)